# Как в тернарном операторе записать больше одного изменения?

Tags: javascript

Знаю про

```
if(){}
else if()
else{}
```

есть вот что :

```js
 
let flag = true;

div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  flag ? 
  div.style.background = "green" flag = false: 
  div.style.background = "red"   flag = true;
})
```

```css
    div{width:100px;height: 30px;background-color: red; color: white;}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  Click
</div>
```

меня интересует именно в тернарном как и можно ли, не используя ***if(){}***, изменять
два и более значений?

Comment: Тернарный оператор придумали для большей наглядности, компактности и ясности, и лучше использовать его только там, где эти условия не будут нарушаться. А код в ответе не очевиден и не читаем.

Comment: @Viniamin ваш вариант явно не читаем и для другого разработчика будет выглядеть ужасно, вы заботитесь только о себе при написании кода, а для других людей которые будут изменять/читать ваш код будет затруднительно что-либо сделать. Научитесь использовать общепринятые стандарты написания кода и таких вопросов как этот попросту не возникнет.

Answer (score 3):

Можно объединить конструкции в скобки, разделив операции запятыми

```
flag
? (
   div.style.background = "green",
   flag = false
  )
: (
   div.style.background = "red",
   flag = true
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Тернарный оператор обычно используют для возвращаемого значения по условию. Нам нужно получить значение цвета для `div.style.background` и здесь тернарный оператор его возвращает. Попутно в условном выражении `flag` логически инвертируется. Уже инвертированное значение будет обработано в условии, поэтому цвета переставлены местами:

```
div.style.background = (flag = !flag) ? 'red': 'green';
```

Думаю, более правильно будет использовать this внутри обработчика события элемента, а потому заменил и стрелочную функцию:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div');
let flag = true;

div.addEventListener('click',  function(){
    this.style.background = (flag = !flag) ? 'red': 'green';
});
```

```html
<div id='div'>DIV</div>
```

Хотя в целом нет такой задачи сократить и ужать донельзя код. Главное - **ЧИТАЕМОСТЬ КОДА!** Сейчас главный критерий хорошего кода - обслуживаемость. Тем более для WEB, где технологии быстро меняются и код необходимо поддерживать, дорабатывать, вносить корректировки. С ним могут работать другие разработчики, можете вы спустя несколько лет.

Comment: IF-ELSE - семантически ясная структура для тех, кто знает немного английский. А ?-: не совсем)) Думаю успех Python как раз и заключается в семантической ясности кода, что в большей степени обеспечивается не самим языком, а принятыми в сообществе правилами.

Comment: @Viniamin, все правильно, на фактический вопрос там есть правильный фактический ответ. Я просто решил оформить свое мнение в другой ответ и, помимо кода, включил свои соображения на этот счет. Я и сам дилетант!

Comment: Тоже поставил плюсик, такой вариант я в другом языке всегда использую. В JS еще не приходилось.